# What are the tools we can use for performance test on aws server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I wanted to do a performance testing on an application hosted on AWS server. SQL  used as the DB.

In order to do a performance test what are the tools that can be used?
Can I use JMeter to run the scripts?
How can I measure server performance ( memory, CPU usage, network)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performance testing tools treat application under test as a ["black box"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) so from performance testing tool perspective it makes absolutely no difference where the application lives: on premise, in cloud, whether it is a single node or a cluster.

So feel free to use either JMeter or [any other performance testing tool](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview).

With regards to measuring server performance given Amazon Infrastructure the most obvious choice would be [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/).

If for some reason you cannot use Amazon CloudWatch you can always stick to [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test), just consider EC2 instance a "normal" server and install [PerfMon Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) there (make sure to open port 4444 for TCP and/or UDP transports in [EC2 Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) and your OS firewall.

Also if you're testing application which is behind [Amazon ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) make sure to add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan